# How to find delicious links?

Tags: links

Delicious links don't show up in Google webmaster tools. I have at least one page with 100+ links from delicious.com to it, since two years ago or more, but webmaster tools doesn't show it. Is there any way to find out whether I have pages linked from delicious somehow?

Comment: Are you looking for an automated tool? Or just how to do it? A search of delicious will turn up your link counts. You just need to search for each page.

Comment: What are delicious links? Having high PR?

Comment: delicious links are links from delicious.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is - Delicious supports the `site:` operator, same as the search engines. So if you search for `site:example.com` it will show everything from example.com. (There doesn't seem to be a way to order them in anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that [Yahoo's Site Explorer](https://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com) will show your delicious tags and bookmark counts.

Comment: This really doesn't seem to work adequately.